# Primes made from alternating factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, factorial

While messing around with factorials, I noticed this:

$$3! - 2! + 1! = 6 - 2 + 1 = 5$$
$$4! - 3! + 2! - 1!= 24 - 6 + 2 - 1=19$$
$$5! - 4! + 3! - 2! + 1! = 5! - 19 = 101$$
$$6! - 5! + 4! - 3! + 2! - 1! = 6! - 101 = 619$$
$$7! - 6! + 5! - 4! + 3! - 2! + 1! = 7! - 619 = 4421$$

Notice that all of the sums are prime.

My question, is, does this pattern (i.e. the results are prime) continue forever?
(If yes, please prove why. If no, please provide a counterexample, and why it happens.)

My attempt was to show that for every positive integer $n > 2$, $(n - 1)! - (n + 2)! + (n + 3)! - (n + 4)! $ (and so on) $ = k$, and prove that $k $ is not divisible by any prime below or equal to $(n - 1)$. (Which by the way, I almost proved it. Will edit this post if I did it.)

But, I am really confused on how to show that $k$ is not divisible by any prime bigger than $(n - 1).$ Is my approach to solve this problem correct?

Comment: The law of small numbers is quite powerful...  The sequence can be taken as $a_n=n!-a_{n-1}$, so that may help further calculations.

Comment: Try $n=9$ for counterexample

Comment: Oops, again I asked a really easy question that has an easy counterexample. I guess I should check at least 15 possibilities first before asking...

Comment: It is still an interesting observation.

Comment: See M. Zivkovic, [The number of primes Sum_{i=1..n} (-1)^(n-i)*i! is finite,](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-99-00990-4) Math. Comp. 68 (1999), pp. 403-409, cited in [OEIS A005165](https://oeis.org/A005165). An OEIS search is the first thing you should try on problems like this.

Comment: What's an OEIS? Also, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this pattern does not continue forever. Quite the opposite - there exist finitely many primes of this form. See https://oeis.org/A071828 and the reference there.

Comment: Is the numbers listed there the only ones out of many?

Comment: No, but you may find proof in the cited reference. It implies that there are at most 3612703 such primes.

Comment: Per https://oeis.org/A001272 only 25 such primes are known, but there may be more.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the OEIS reference!